# Input Function Skip. Applied fix. Odd result

Tags: c, newline

I have a **simple program,** intended simply to excercise my freshly gained knowledge of C.

Please keep in mind I have attempted to solve the problem of the **newline leftovers** remaining in the **stdin buffer** using the knowledge I already have. From the problems I was having before I figured out the newline issue, I have made considerable progress in getting this program to act the way I imagine it should. This is all I have left to debug and **I am stymied.** While my **fluency in C is marginal,** at best, I believe this program can easily work **without a whole lot of modification.**

The program asks the user to select a tool, of 2 simple tools I have constructed. The tools themselves work fine, but the cheesy **'pick-a-letter' UI** that I've built has a **bug** I just can't figure out. It runs through the program **as expected the first time,** but the **second time,** the variable used for tool selection gets **switched to a newline** character, and the user input assignment for that variable gets overwritten. Therefore the program enters the switch construct used for the tool selection variable and activates:

```
case '\n':
```

which prints an error message indicating a newline got in the way, and breaks out to return to the beginning of the menu loop. On this **third time around, the program will again work as expected.** It will continue to alternate like this until you exit the program via the exit provided at the end of a normal program run.

This is a direct cut and paste of pertainant code, not included are the D_Time(); and cal(); functions. Feel free to compile and run with substitue functions to see the problem firsthand if need be. Both are void functions, one is a simple 2 argument calculator and the other displays date and time via stdout. And any other suggestions you have that could improve my knowledge of C or this program would be happily accepted and are sought. I am still learning, and although pointers and calculus escape me, i will get the hang of this.

```
void clrnl(void)
{
    while (getc(stdin) != '\n');
} /* This is the fix that kind-of but not-really fixes the '\n' problem. Without it, the error message would pop up every time i used the menu, not including the first run. */

void menu(void)
{
    char tool = 1;
    int r = 0;
    while (r != 1)
    {
        printf("\n ---Select a tool.---\n\n ------------------\n\n C = Calculator\n\n D = Date/Time\n\n ");
        tool = getc(stdin);
        clrnl(); /* This seems to be the only line where clrnl(); has a positive effect. */
        switch (tool)
        {
            case 'D':
                printf("\n You selected Date/Time ");
                D_Time();
                r = 1;
                break;
            case 'C':
                printf("\n You selected Calculator ");
                cal();
                r = 1;
                break;
            case 'd':
                printf("\n You selected Date/Time ");
                D_Time();
                r = 1;
                break;
            case 'c':
                printf("\n You selected Calculator ");
                cal();
                r = 1;
                break;
            case '\n':
                printf("\n Error!! -- Newline character detected!! Try again.\n\n");
                r = 0;
                break;
            default:
                printf("\n Error!! -- Unknown. Try again.\n\n");
                r = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    char lx;
    do
    {
        menu();
        printf("\n Enter 'x' to exit.\n\n ");
        scanf(" %c", &lx);
        if (lx != 'x')
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
    while (lx != 'x');
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you input your selection, for example `D`, and you press enter key, various things can happen. If you're on windows, your application will recieve characters: `'D', '\r', '\n'`. On linux, it will be `'D','\n'`. To eat up any extra input read by `scanf` use this simple trick:

```
scanf(" %c*", &lx);
```

The `*` in format string will skip your carriage return and newline characters.

This is changed code for tool selection:

```
    printf("\n ---Select a tool.---\n\n ------------------\n\n C = Calculator\n\n D = Date/Time\n\n ");
    scanf(" %c*", &tool);
```

This is the part for the exit input:

```
    printf("\n Enter 'x' to exit.\n\n ");
    scanf(" %c*", &lx);
```

You can further put more switch cases together like this to reduce code duplication:

```
case 'D':
case 'd':
    printf("\n You selected Date/Time ");
    D_Time();
    r = 1;
    break;
```

This will work, because there's no break statement after `case 'D'`, so if this case happens, the code continues pass the `case 'd':` line into the corresponding code.

Answer (score 2):

Usually a context menu is not waiting for the user to press enter before getting the option while your loop does it.
In order to select the option when pressing the relevant key instead waiting for the "enter" you can call OS specific functions. Under linux reconfigure your terminal using `system ("/bin/stty raw")` just before entering in your while loop and than leave things as they are. Under windows consider `_getch()` instead of getc(stdin).
Remember that **getchar() and getc()** return an **integer** and not a char.
Doing this you have a more reactive menu and you don't need to handle the extra chars generated.